# Conditional AND statement when searching in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure to search the customers table via admin panel.
I have it working for the most part, and when I pass the CustomerRoles (separated customer role ids) I get the customers in those roles returned.

However if I don't pass any customer roles in (so an empty string) I get no records, but I would like it to return all roles.

This is the part I'm concerned with

```
    AND (@CustomerRoles IS null OR EXISTS (
        SELECT [Customer_Id], [CustomerRole_Id] FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping] crm with (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE c.Id = crm.Customer_Id AND crm.[CustomerRole_Id] IN (SELECT CustomerRoleId FROM #FilteredCustomerRolesIds)))
```

I can confirm a null value is passed into the stored procedure when no CustomerRoles are searched for.

I figure I need some kind of null check or coalesce expression but not sure how to go about it.

Here is my full stored procedure

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CustomerLoadAllPaged]    Script Date: 10/2/2020 8:20:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


--new stored procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomerLoadAllPaged]
(
    @CustomerRoles nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @CustomerEmail nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @FirstName nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @LastName nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @PageIndex int = 0, 
    @PageSize int = 2147483644,
    @TotalRecords int = null OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    create table #TempCust (RowNum int identity(1,1), id int);
    create index #IK_tempcust on #TempCust (RowNum);

    SET @CustomerRoles = isnull(@CustomerRoles, '') 
    CREATE TABLE #FilteredCustomerRolesIds
    (
        CustomerRoleId int not null
    )
    INSERT INTO #FilteredCustomerRolesIds (CustomerRoleId)
    SELECT CAST(data as int) FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@CustomerRoles, ',')
    DECLARE @CustomerRoleIdCount int    
    SET @CustomerRoleIdCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #FilteredCustomerRolesIds)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --select all
    INSERT INTO #TempCust ([id])
        SELECT c.[Id] 
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer] c with (NOLOCK)

    LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Address] a with (NOLOCK) on a.Id = c.BillingAddress_Id and (
        coalesce(@CustomerEmail,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@FirstName,'') <> ''
        or coalesce(@LastName,'') <> ''
    )

    /*LEFT join [Test].[dbo].[Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping] crm with (NOLOCK) on c.Id = crm.Customer_Id and (
        coalesce(@CustomerRoles,'') <> ''
    )*/

    WHERE (@CustomerEmail IS null OR c.[Email] LIKE CONCAT('%',@CustomerEmail,'%'))
    AND (@FirstName IS null OR a.[FirstName] LIKE CONCAT('%',@FirstName,'%'))
    AND (@LastName IS null OR a.[LastName] LIKE CONCAT('%',@LastName,'%'))
    --AND (crm.[CustomerRole_Id] IN (SELECT CustomerRoleId FROM #FilteredCustomerRolesIds))

    AND (@CustomerRoles IS null OR EXISTS (
        SELECT [Customer_Id], [CustomerRole_Id] FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping] crm with (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE c.Id = crm.Customer_Id AND crm.[CustomerRole_Id] IN (SELECT CustomerRoleId FROM #FilteredCustomerRolesIds)))

    --ORDER BY c.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC;
    
    --paging
    DECLARE @PageLowerBound int
    SET @PageLowerBound = @PageSize * @PageIndex

    -- Return the paged records
    select [Id] --note select * can produce unexpected results
      ,[CustomerGuid]
      ,[Username]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Password]
      ,[PasswordFormatId]
      ,[PasswordSalt]
      ,[AdminComment]
      ,[IsTaxExempt]
      ,[AffiliateId]
      ,[VendorId]
      ,[HasShoppingCartItems]
      ,[Active]
      ,[Deleted]
      ,[IsSystemAccount]
      ,[SystemName]
      ,[LastIpAddress]
      ,[CreatedOnUtc]
      ,[LastLoginDateUtc]
      ,[LastActivityDateUtc]
      ,[BillingAddress_Id]
      ,[ShippingAddress_Id]
    from [Test].[dbo].[Customer] cust with (NOLOCK)
    where cust.[Id] in (
      select id
      from #TempCust tc
      --Where (tc.RowNum > @PageLowerBound) -- best to use offset like below, which is faster and recommended
    )
    ORDER BY cust.[CreatedOnUtc] DESC
    OFFSET @PageLowerBound ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
    
    --total records
    select @TotalRecords = count(*) from #TempCust;

    DROP TABLE #TempCust
    DROP TABLE #FilteredCustomerRolesIds
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you ensure that `@CustomerRoles` is never `null` with the following line:

```
SET @CustomerRoles = ISNULL(@CustomerRoles, '');
```

You need to compare to a blank string instead of `null` e.g.

```
AND (
  -- @CustomerRoles IS NULL -- Change to empty string check since it is never null
  @CustomerRoles = ''
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT [Customer_Id], [CustomerRole_Id]
    FROM [Test].[dbo].[Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping] crm WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE c.Id = crm.Customer_Id AND crm.[CustomerRole_Id] IN (SELECT CustomerRoleId FROM #FilteredCustomerRolesIds)
  )
)
```

As an aside you shouldn't use the `nolock` hint unless its absolutely required for performance.

Comment: Good point on the no lock too, I don't think it's required on that table, will update that :)

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not the same thing as `NULL`.  If you are passing an empty string, you want to compare to `''`.  Or perhaps you want to be safe and consider both possibilities:

```
AND (@CustomerRoles IS null OR
     @CustomerRoles = '' OR
     EXISTS ( . . . )
    )
```

Comment: @Dale k beat u by like 5 seconds, but you at least deserve the up vote :)
I like the way you have the null and empty string check